# Split a string with "|" Char to columns

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm a bit new to this language so I have several doubts.
I'm working to process an xml to display some data on pdf form.
But there a few strings that have "|" so I can split the data to display properly.
Here is the example of the input data:

```
<root>
  <reference>
    <NroLinRef>12</NroLinRef>
    <CodRef>I20</CodRef>
    <RazonRef>Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4|Data5|Data6|Data7</RazonRef>
  </reference>
</root>
```

In the output I need something like this so I can display in order in row with cells so data must be clear to read.

```
<root>
  <Reference>
    <NroLinRef>12</NroLinRef>
    <CodRef>I20</CodRef>
    <Data1>Data1</Data1>
    <Data2>Data2</Data2>
    <Data3>Data3</Data3>
    <Data4>Data4</Data4>
    <Data5>Data5</Data5>
    <Data6>Data6</Data6>
    <Data7>Data7</Data7>
  </Reference>
</root>
```

To do this I have been using other code that is from another question but can't find how to get the name to be updated or customized.

And the output I get is actually like this:

```
<root>
  <Reference>
    <NroLinRef>12</NroLinRef>
    <CodRef>I20</CodRef>
    <Data>Data1</Data>
    <Data>Data2</Data>
    <Data>Data3</Data>
    <Data>Data4</Data>
    <Data>Data5</Data>
    <Data>Data6</Data>
    <Data>Data7</Data>
  </Reference>
</root>
```

This is the XSL i'm using

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="Referencia/RazonRef" name="tokenize">
           <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                    <Data>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
                    </Data>
                </xsl:when>         
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Data>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                    </Data>
                    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I get the output I want?

Comment: If you're already getting the result, I don't understand what you're asking here.... what do you mean by updated/customized?

Comment: **1.** Please post your current XSLT stylesheet so we can modify it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. **2** Are you sure you want the format you show? it's not a good XML format to have.

Comment: Let me explain more about the problem, i have generated and xml that need to be used in 2 different files for the output, because of that i have that string separated witn "|" it works without trouble in one format that is PDF to display the data, the problem y when i need to display the same data using xslt.

Comment: @michael.hor257k
Thanks for your help.
Let me explain more about the problem, i have generated and xml that need to be used in 2 different files for the output, because of that i have that string separated witn "|" it works without trouble in one format that is PDF to display the data, the problem y when i need to display the same data using xslt.
In cells to the right in a row.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your explanation. I have modified your stylesheet to produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The expected result can be achieved by applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RazonRef" name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:element name="Data{$i}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $separator), $separator)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $separator)">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```